# Чем и как забэкапить микросервер с Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Привет. Раньше арендовал микросервер у Reg.ru и у них была удобная штука для бэкапов, где можно было получить архив всей системы в `.tar` и загрузить его себе куда-нибудь. Сейчас съехал от них к другому хостеру, у которого есть возможность хранить только один снапшот без возможности скачать его к себе на компьютер и нет возможности делать бэкапы из панели управления вообще (ибо KVM). Так вот, как можно упаковать всё, что находится в корне в `.tar`-архив для хранения?

Comment: Я использую Clonezilla

Comment: Т.е. "bios" ты всё-таки можешь прогрузить и выбрать какой-нить iso для загрузки?

Answer (score 2):

`tar cvjpf <имя_бэкапа>.tar.bz2 <список директорий>`

Флаги:

- `-c` Создать новый архив
- `-v` Выводить логи по ходу создания архива(дабы быть уверенным в том, что машинка не подвисла)
- `-j` Сжать при помощи `bzip2`
- `-p` Сохранить файлы вместе с правами доступа
- `-f` Имя архива (использовать файл архива)

Ещё можно почитать по данной ссылке:
[Full system backup with tar](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Full_system_backup_with_tar)

Comment: Спасибо! А аргумент `<список директорий>` может принимать параметр `*`, то есть "все"?

Comment: Можно указать `/`. Это скопирует всё.

Comment: там архив сам себя увидит)

Comment: А еще он будет долго архивировать /dev/, особенно /dev/zero, /dev/random и /dev/urandom